Meaning of "Call (God) holy"
Oxford English Online Dictionary defines the word "bless" in one sense as follows:

(especially in Christian church services) call (God) holy; praise (God).

I've got difficulty interpreting the first part of the definition, i.e. "call (God) holy", specifically with the parentheses wrapping around "God". As I understand the parentheses means optionality so the definition could be rewritten as:

call (God) holy
call holy

Also, the phrase "to call something/someone + adj." means that to consider or describe somebody/something to be something or in a specific way. So "to call God holy" means to consider God holy, but what about "call holy" then? As no information about the verb type (i.e. intransitive or transitive) is provided for this definition and no example for this entry exists so I don't know how to create examples of this definition.
Could someone help to explain this definition in more detail, examples would be greatly appreciated!

I don't understand "Call (God) holy". The most common usage is "Bless you!" That's often just a standard response to someone sneezing, said by people who have no idea that in medieval times it was thought the Devil could invade your body through the sneezing mouth. So in that context, it's really an "imperative" praying for "May God bless you! (and keep the Devil at bay)". So perhaps it should be defined as "(God) call holy". Only God (and priests acting in His name) can normally "bless" anything or anyone.

When a priest blesses a chalice, he 'calls it holy' (deems or declares it to be holy).

Some Catholics and Orthodox believers calling crossing yourself 'blessing yourself'.

@FumbleFingers certainly in Judaism it's commonplace to bless God; the short prayers before performing an action (of which there are hundreds) all start "Blessed are You God, King of the Universe..."

@DanielRoseman - the Catholics say a whole bunch: Blessed be God. Blessed be His Holy Name. Blessed be Jesus Christ, true God and true Man. Blessed be the Name of Jesus. Blessed be His Most Sacred Heart... (it goes on; 14 things altogether) "The Divine Praises".

re "what about 'call'": as you said, it means to consider or describe. Most uses of "call [noun] [adj]" involve or imply assertion or even proclamation. If I "call you a liar," yes, I consider it so, but it's implied that I either say so or would be willing to if asked. Most injunctions to "bless God" are injunctions to overt acts of worship.

In this setting, the parentheses don't indicate that the word God is optional. Rather, they mean that for this definition, the typical direct object of bless will be God.
The OED definition in question gives several examples of this usage, and God (or a pronoun referring to God) is the direct object in all of them. For example

Stand up and bless the Lord, The Lord your God adore.

This sort of notation is common in dictionaries, especially for words or usages that can be used only in specific contexts. For another example, consider this definition of the verb wreak, which includes

to exercise or gratify (wrath, anger, etc.)

So, one can wreak havoc or wreak destruction. But the parentheses tell us that wreak is a synonym of to exercise or gratify only when discussing some violent emotion like anger. One cannot wreak one's goodwill on the community — or rather, putting it that way would imply that the speaker thinks poorly of the goodwill in question. The material in parentheses is not optional; quite the opposite, it tells us the contexts in which this usage is appropriate.
In your case, the dictionary adds the parenthetical because in most uses of bless, the object is not being called holy, but rather being made holy (or one is asking a deity to make it holy, etc). So the OED is noting that this alternative meaning of calling something holy is applicable more or less only when the direct object is God.

This is the ultimate answer that I'm looking for. Thanks a lot, Dave!
